# How to handle login action using action filter in nopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, action-filter

I am using nopCommerce3.40

I have create one plugin and i want open custom page from plugin so i have used `action filter` and its working fine after login my custom page opened.

But some time customer enter wrong email or password so nopCommerce login event set error in `ModelState.AddModelError` then instantly my page call and i am just check current customer is guest so redirect login page so its work fine but error message not display because login page is reload.

**In Short if Customer was not successfully login then debug point should no reach to my action and how to get ModelState is true or not in actionfilter?**

please give me suggestion how to handle login action using action filter

Regards,
Jatin

Comment: try to put condition on action filter, i thing there is you get data to just check data that success or error message and according to that load page, your custom or existing login with error msg.

Comment: Hello @Vap but what should i check in action filter?

Comment: are you use after result or on login run time?i thing you are call yr metho after login result, so check on filter time that what result return by login method and accroding to that call your method or function. now you get my point

Comment: thank you @Vap i got idea how works see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution see code look like: In actionfilter

```
 public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
                var viewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;
                if (viewData.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                        //some code 

                }
        }
```